# Powershell - send output to excel file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have a script that creates a table from scanning 10's of thousands of files.  The output of the table ends up on the screen.  I need to take that screen output and convert it to something that can be ingested into excel.  Most likely a CSV file.

This is the code that takes a previously created table and extracts the information I need, then prints it on the screen.

Would someone be able to help me convert this information to a CSV file where the HASH and FULL Name would be the headings for the two columns and then the Hash data in column 1 under the Hash heading and the full name data in column 2 under the full name heading?

```
# output duplicates
& { foreach($key in $result.Keys)
{
    foreach($file in $result[$key])
    {
        $file |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $key -PassThru | 
            Select-Object Hash, Length, FullName 
    }
}
} | Format-Table -GroupBy Hash -Property FullName
```

Here is what the output looks like on the screen

Hash: 7827DDE006149320136B029A866282F40C109EE3:12231

### FullName

C:\P$$$RA1.pl1
C:\src\P$$$RA1.pl1

Hash: D230CF0EA5C31AF21C82338AFE1FE5E7FB9E1A2E:709

### FullName

C:$ISPMLIB.proc
C:\src$ISPMLIB
C:\source-code$ISPMLIB.proc

Hash: 138F79F72D56B5ECB8C3C3B7F584962C6A3750E2:11421

### FullName

C:\Z$SDENT.pl1
C:\src\Z$SDENT.pl1

Comment: I commend your attention to the [`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!
I'm very new to Powershell, however I'll give that a try.
Regards,
-Ron

Comment: If you want to directly produce and Excel (not .csv) file, I would commend the `ImportExcel` module to you.

Answer (score 0):

See comments to question - Export to CSV worked great

Comment: To identify the best answer, please select the check mark of the answer. This answer can be deleted. If the answer is from a comment, leave a comment that it is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)